# VMware Fusion Ubuntu 16.04.3 black screen during shutdown

Tags: 16.04, shutdown

My Ubuntu 16.04.3 guest OS on VMware Fusion doesn't work. When I shutdown, it stopped showing a black screen.
I have waited, but it stopped all day. It is twice.
What's the problem? And how can I force it to shutdown properly?

Here is a screenshot of the state of my Ubuntu.

[image]